# Sass css not working on ubuntu? Not listening or compiling

Tags: css, ruby, rubygems, sass

Sass should be relatively easy to set up, which I did.

Oddly enough I set up a folder such as

```
cd Desktop/sass
```

then activate...

```
sass --watch style.s.css:style.css
```

All seems well...

```
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
      write style.css
[Listen warning]:
  Listen will be polling for changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback.
```

Run a quick test in style.s.css...save...

```
body{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

According to tutorial, it should "detect" changes (because it's listening) and compile them, while notifying via terminal. But that does not happen.

So to jog it, I CTRL-C and run the command again...

Get an error (on valid css?)

```
Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
      error style.s.css (Line 2: Invalid CSS after "#fff": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";")
[Listen warning]:
  Listen will be polling for changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback.
```

This is quite a mystery. It hardly seems as though it should go wrong...

What is happening here to cause it not to listen and throw silly errors?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Reason: Developer is idiot.

I had **style.s.css** whereas it should have been **style.scss**